# Google maps multi-color polyline

Tags: javascript, colors, maps, google-polyline

I have a Google maps page that draws various polylines based on a bunch of coordinates. They all connect two points via a great circle polyline. All lines have the same color. These lines are routes on a network

I would now like to make the polylines in a fading color to indicate the profitability of the route, showing a green color for profitable routes and red for loss making routes. As each polyline has two possible profitabilities (from both originating points) the colors should fade over to the other color gradually.

I assume, I could split the polyline into two, showing each only half of the line, but then the color would not gradually fade into the other.

Is there a way to do that?

Currently I am creating the lines as follows:

```
var routes = [['CJU', 'SZX', 33.5112991333, 126.49299621582, 22.6392993927, 113.81099700928, 1, 7, 3163768],
['CJU', 'PEK', 33.5112991333, 126.49299621582, 40.08010101318, 116.58499908447, 0.5, 4, 3163766],
['CJU', 'PVG', 33.5112991333, 126.49299621582, 31.14340019226, 121.80500030518, 0.5, 4, 3163767],
['CJU', 'WUH', 33.5112991333, 126.49299621582, 30.78380012512, 114.20800018311, 0.5, 4, 3163769],];

function setRoutes(map, flights) {
        for (var j = 0; j < flights.length; j++) {
            var route  = flights[j];
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'From '+route[0]+' to '+route[1]+' ', position: new google.maps.LatLng(route[4], route[5]) });

            var flt    = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [new google.maps.LatLng(route[2], route[3]), new google.maps.LatLng(route[4], route[5])], strokeColor: "#FF0000", strokeOpacity: route[6], strokeWeight: route[7], geodesic: true, url: 'http://domain.com/page.asp?F='+route[8] });
            flt.setMap(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(flt, 'click', function() { NewWindow(this.url,'name','770','490','Yes');return false; });
            var apt    = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://domain.com/marker/dot.png', null, null, new google.maps.Point(8,14), new google.maps.Size(20,20));
            var dep    = new google.maps.LatLng(route[2], route[3]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: dep, map: map, icon: apt, title: route[0]});
            var arr    = new google.maps.LatLng(route[4], route[5]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: arr, map: map, icon: apt, title: route[1]});
        }
    }

setRoutes(map, routes);
```

This works just fine, but I'm not sure how I could have the color gradually fade over from a color1 to a color2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The google maps documentation does not have any option to fade colors.
They will appear fixed, However a little bit of customization can be done but fading from one color to another is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving colors in RGBA mode.

I mean instead of Giving colors in Hex mode e.g. #FF0000, you can use it's equivalent in RGBA mode e.g. rgba(255, 0, 0, 1).

To fade your colors in RGBA mode, change the value of last digit and keep it between 0 (transparent) and 1 (visible).

You can use this [link](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/) to convert your Hex colors to RGBA.